# Unable to import fbx file

Tags: import, .fbx

When trying to import a .fbx model in Blender, I get an error dialog telling me that there is no disk in the drive E:, and freezes the program.

Comment: What is drive E: on your system? On my system E: is the name of the CD-RW drive. When you get to the file browser in Blender, make certain that you're trying to import from the drive that the file is actually on. If, as it happens, you're trying to import the file from a CD in the drive, then you have bad media, or a bad drive.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I actually don't have a drive E. My files are saved on my C drive under User/Documents.

Comment: Found my error. There was a USB Drive E that was hidden. Had to uninstall it from Device Manager. Thank you @brasshat